# Using Excel Interop and getting a print dialog

Tags: c#, interop, printing

I have the following code: [Thank you Mike Rosenblum!]

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication17
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //public void PrintMyExcelFile() 
            //{
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            // Open the Workbook:
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(
                @"C:\hello.xls",
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            // Get the first worksheet.
            // (Excel uses base 1 indexing, not base 0.)
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];

            // Print out 1 copy to the default printer:
            ws.PrintOut(
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            // Cleanup:
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ws);

            wb.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wb);

            excelApp.Quit();
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApp);
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is that instead of this printing my Excel file right away, I'd like a print dialog to appear so that I may choose a specific printer if I'd like. I'm using the 12.0.0.0 .NET interop for Excel. Anybody have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The print dialog is accessible from .NET and will run just fine on Excel 2007 using the 12.0 PIAs. The Dialog.Show() command, however, has 30 optional parameters. In the future, C# 4.0 will allow for omitting optional parameters (thank goodness), and VB.NET does not require them, but if using C# 3.0 or below, we have to provide Type.Missing for the optional parameters. All 30 of them:

```
bool userDidntCancel =
    excelApp.Dialogs[Excel.XlBuiltInDialog.xlDialogPrint].Show(
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

The the Show() method returns 'true' to indicate that the operation succeeded; it returns 'false' to indicate that the user hit the cancel button or the escape (esc) key, so no action occurred.

Hope this gets you going...

Comment: again, THANK YOU for being a lifesaver!!  your help is VERY appreciated

Comment: I had gone through the codings above. I too have a problem in a similar process i.e Print Preview option.

Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();

            Excel.Workbook wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\\Documents and Settings \\Admin \\Desktop \\DoCoMo\\ news5.xls",Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,               Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,                            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];

Comment: After trying the solution, the printer dialog doesn't pop up. My website just hangs forever. Do you the possible way to rectify it? Thanks!

Comment: @john - website hangs? I wouldn't try this from server side code. This means the print dialog is probably showing up on the server and yes, it will hang.